# What things need to keep in Mind while developing multithread Javafx application?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, javafx-8

I'm new to Javafx and developing an IDE using this. The problem i'm facing with JavaFX is that i have to use `Platform.runLater()` to reflect changes in GUI from other threads. As my IDE i'm developing use multiple threads to keep up to date information and using `Platform.runLater()` makes application unresponsive. And sometime background processes has to print output of millions of line which i think cause problem when multiple threads try to do same. I tried to put a counter so that if output is larger than 250000 lines it will print output after 250000 lines else in other case it will print immediately after completion of the thread, even in this case if two or more thread try to execute `Platform.runLater()` (also there are other threads which creates tree with checkbox items and reflect realtime values) application hangs but everything in background is keep running normally and even application doesn't throw any exception. In normal java swing app i didn't face any similar problem. So i'm seeking guidance to tackle these problems. Can somebody gave me PRO tips to solve similar problems? :)

**Edit On The request of @jewelsea**

I tried to keep the sample code as simple as possible

**FxUI.java**

```
 public class FxUI extends Application {
 public static TextArea outputArea;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    outputArea= new TextArea();
    Button btn = new Button();

    btn.setText("Start Appending Text To Text Area");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          Thread r=new Thread( new Runnable() {

               @Override
               public void run() {
              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Thread t= new Thread(new simpleThread(i));
            t.start();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Thread Awake");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FxUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }  }
           });
          r.start();
        }
    });

    VBox root = new VBox(30);
    outputArea.setWrapText(true);
    outputArea.setPrefHeight(400);
    root.getChildren().add(outputArea);
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

**simpleThread.java**

```
 public class simpleThread implements Runnable {

int threadnumber;

public simpleThread(int j) {
    threadnumber = j;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    String output = "";
    String content;
    int length;
    final String finalcontent2;
    final int finallength2;

    for (long i = 0L; i <= 10000; i++) {
        final String finalcontent;
        final int finallength;

        if (i % 1000 == 0) {
            output += "\nThread number = " + threadnumber + " \t Loop Counter=" + i;
            content = FxUI.outputArea.getText() + "\n" + output;
            length = content.length();
            finallength = length;
            finalcontent = "" + content;
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("appending output");
                    FxUI.outputArea.setText(finalcontent);
                    FxUI.outputArea.positionCaret(finallength);

                }
            });
        } else {
            output += "\nThread number = " + threadnumber + " \t Loop Counter=" + i;

        }
        System.out.println("Thread number = " + threadnumber + " \t Loop Counter=" + i);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: You should supply an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jewelsea New edit, tried to replicate the problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the first real issue here is that your code is simply massively inefficient. Building up a string in a loop is a really bad thing to do: you create a new object and copy all the characters every time. Additionally, each time you update the text area, you are copying the entire existing text, creating another `String` by concatenating the additional content, and then replacing all the existing content with the new content. The string concatenation is going to run in quadratic time (as you are increasing the length of the strings each time) and you're going to cause mayhem for Java's string interning process.

Also, note that you shouldn't read the state of a node in the scene graph anywhere except on the FX application thread, so your line

```
        content = FxUI.outputArea.getText() + "\n" + output;
```

is not thread-safe.

In general, to build up a string in a loop, you should use a `StringBuilder` to build up the string contents. If you're using a `TextArea`, it has an `appendText(...)` method which is all you need to update it.

**Update** following discussion in comments:

Having made those general comments, making those improvements doesn't really get you to a state where the performance is acceptable. My observation there is that the `TextArea` is slow to respond to user input even after the threads have completed. The issue is (I guess) that you have a large amount of data which is actually associated with a "live" part of the scene graph.

A better option here is probably to use a virtualized control such as a `ListView` to display the data. These only have cells for the visible portion and reuse them as the user scrolls. Here is an example. I added selection and copy-to-clipboard functionality as that is the main thing you would miss going from a `TextArea` to a `ListView`. (Note that if you have a huge number of things selected, the `String.join()` method is very slow to run. You might have to create a background task for that and a blocking dialog to show its progress if that's important.)

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BigListBackgroundThreadDemo extends Application {

    private static final int NUM_ITERATIONS = 10_000 ;
    private static final int NUM_THREADS_PER_CALL = 5 ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<String> data = new ListView<>();
        data.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        Button startButton = new Button("Start");
        Button selectAllButton = new Button("Select All");
        Button selectNoneButton = new Button("Clear Selection");
        Button copyToClipboardButton = new Button("Copy to clipboard");
        copyToClipboardButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(data.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));

        AtomicInteger threadCount = new AtomicInteger();
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5, r -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t ;
        });

        startButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            exec.submit(() -> {
                for (int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS_PER_CALL; i++) {
                    exec.submit(createTask(threadCount, data));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                        throw new Error("Unexpected interruption", exc);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        selectAllButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            data.getSelectionModel().selectAll();
            data.requestFocus();
        });
        selectNoneButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            data.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            data.requestFocus();
        });

        copyToClipboardButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
            clipboardContent.putString(String.join("\n", data.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));
            Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(clipboardContent);
        });

        HBox controls = new HBox(5, startButton, selectAllButton, selectNoneButton, copyToClipboardButton);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(data, null, null, controls, null);


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Task<Void> createTask(AtomicInteger threadCount, ListView<String> target) {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                int count = threadCount.incrementAndGet();
                AtomicBoolean pending = new AtomicBoolean(false);
                BlockingQueue<String> messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
                for (int i=0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++) {
                    messages.add("Thread number: "+count + "\tLoop counter: "+i);
                    if (pending.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            pending.set(false);
                            messages.drainTo(target.getItems());
                            target.scrollTo(target.getItems().size()-1);
                        });
                    }
                }

                return null ;
            }
        };
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"post the Runnable to an event queue and then return immediately to the caller"_ i think using `javafx.concurrent` will not help bcz it will return to the caller and all threads will execute immediatley but it will post output according to its place in the queue. Thanks for your reply that helped a little bit also we can use `FxUI.outputArea.getLength()` instead `FxUI.outputArea.getText().length()`.

Comment: i think javafx is better for small applications but we can't consider it for developing large scale or very large scale applications which i'm trying to do. Am i right? I will be happy if you share your thoughts with me. I'm not expert but I never faced such issue in LS or VLS swing apps. How javafx will be useful if it cant show us values in Real-Time?

Comment: I don't really understand your first comment. As for large-scale applications, I think it probably depends on what you mean by large scale. I have used JavaFX to display fairly large data sets (genomics; so we deal with tables referencing of the order of millions of records at a time) and the performance has been fine. My observation with your code is that it actually performs pretty badly even after the thread has completed. So a `TextArea` is probably not a good choice for the UI when you have a lot of data. Consider implementing with a `ListView` instead.

Comment: :) you stole thoughts from my mind (for that all credits will go to you), i was going to do that but i was trying to work with `TextArea`. In a swing app i designed two years ago i used `JList` to represent Lengthy data. And by Large scale apps mean app i'm developing is a parallel computing framework which i think is pretty large when considering multiple threads running here and there and  multiple machines communicating with each other. The problem i'm facing is real time representation of data graphically. Javafx takes a lot of time to reflect change on GUI.

Comment: And i choose `TextArea` bcz of it's flexibility to select output.

Comment: Updated answer per discussion.

Comment: i just clicked select all button during execution and app become unresponsive, I think javafx is still not mature to design large scale multithreaded apps. And i totally accept my coding abilities are not that efficient as compare to world's best programmers(u r also):P. And i'm not jumping to any conclusion, i will try develop the app in JavaFX and will release another version in swing. Using a single queue to manage all UI interactions is not a good policy followed by Javafx , i think seperate queue for each Graphical element will be better. I'm a thinker, developers know better.:)

Comment: For the design choices, Swing is also a single-threaded framework, so I don't really understand why you think there's a difference there. There is just one AWT event thread on which all Swing controls have to be updated.

Comment: 2 years ago i created download manager for Linux in java and used multiple threads to download files and in similar manner i used above i also reflected changes on UI from the downloading threads. i also used observer in the table view to fetch progress. At that time i also created an simple C-worm detector which also used multiple threads in BG.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like [your swing code is broken](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading), and is prone to silently producing incorrect results at undetermined (if rare) moments. You should also look at the [relevant section in the tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: That helped a lot, i learned a lot of things from you :), institutes here only teach you how to code, not how to code better :). From the beginning i relied on internet to learn coding. From now on i will focus more on writing a better and efficient code. thanks for pointing out all the things. BTW my swing apps never froze or became unresponsive as given in second link.

Comment: They might not freeze or become unresponsive, but you have absolutely no guarantee they are producing the correct output. One of the advantages of JavaFX 8 over Swing is that if you get the threading wrong it will throw an exception. Swing just silently proceeds with the possibility that the UI is showing incorrect data.

Comment: i try to implement multithreading only on independent tasks, i may not be the best programmer or better than you :) but i posses knowledge about these things. And i'm not being stubborn, i have full confidence in my apps. On interdependent tasks i use threadpools. :). I will try to publish my code under GPL license. LOLz you are really underestimating me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62993/discussion-between-james-d-and-deepsidhu1313).

Comment: Tried a lot of things, but listview worked great. Added one more option to open output in TextArea, then all worked well for me as i required. thank you sir :)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaFX you have to do your background process in a [Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) which run a [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) . By doing this you'll won't freez your GUI thread

Quick example, if you want a String as a return value of your process.

The service :

```
    public class MyService extends Service<String> {
    @Override
    protected Task<String> createTask() {
        return new Task<String>() {
            @Override
            protected String call() throws Exception {
                //Do your heavy stuff
                return "";
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Place you want to use your service  :

```
    final MyService service = new MyService();

    service.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        //your service finish with no problems
        service.getValue(); //get the return value of your service
    });

    service.setOnFailed(e -> {
        //your service failed
    });

    service.restart();
```

You have other method like setOnFailed, for the different status. So implement what you need.
You can also monitor this service, But I let you read the doc for this. It's quit simple.

You should also read [JavaFX concurency](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)

Comment: I think, you should duplicate these samples with lambdas, which are much shorter and easier to read.

Comment: And, by the way, if your task is not returning something, is typically parametrized with [`Void`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html).

Comment: wrapping a task in a service isnt actually necessary, in fact that will make it harder to stop all of the remaining tasks during application-shutdown

Comment: @agonist_ how implementing service in place of normal java thread will make difference? bcz all of my background processes run on Java Threads, nothinh heavy runs on my UI thread except updating text areas for output and tree view .. While writing this comment i got one thing in my mind, i have to get all the text from textarea and then append my output to it each time, if i am printing millions of lines of output, may be javafx becoming unresponsive because of i am getting millions of text in Platorm.runlater and appending the text in same function... I think so....

Comment: @agonist_ [Platform Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html) According to this you can call this method from any thread and you have to call it minimum time as possible. :)